# Need a two dropdown in html to show different json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I want to display two different values from json in two different dropdowns in html but its not displaying. I am currently using the following code : 
How to separate Name in one dropdown and Age in the other dropdown in js.
Here is my json data :

{
"action": [

{"name":"Ankit","age":"23"},
{"name":"Ankit2","age":"23"}

]

}

```js
$(document).ready( function(){

$.getJSON("jsondata.json",function(data){
$.each(data.action,function(){
$("select").append("<option>Name: "+this['name']+"</option><option>Age: "+this['age']+"</option><br/>");
});
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<select>
</select>
<select>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `id` attribute to both selects to be able to select with jQuery easily.
I also added your sample json data to http://jsbin.com/pegabe/1.json.

```
$.each(data.action, function() {
  nameDropdown.append($("<option></option>")
               .text('Name:' + this['name']));

  ageDropdown.append($("<option></option>")
               .text('Age:' + this['age']));
});
```

---

> nameDropdown is the reference to `<select id="name"></select>`
>
> `$('<option></option>')` - creates a `<option></option>`
>
> .text('Name:' + this['name']) - appends text to the option like this `<option>Name: + this['name']</option>`
>
> finally this option is appended to nameDropdown.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON("http://jsbin.com/pegabe/1.json", function(data) {
    var nameDropdown = $("#name"); // dropdown for name
    var ageDropdown = $("#age"); // dropdown for age

    $.each(data.action, function() {
      nameDropdown.append($("<option></option>")
                   .text('Name:' + this['name']));
      
      ageDropdown.append($("<option></option>")
                   .text('Age:' + this['age']));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <select id="name">
  </select>
  <select id="age">
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/myscript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: working fine. thnx... would be grt if you could explain me the jquery code from $each.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML slightly, Add `ID` to `select` element

```
<select id="name">
</select>
<select id="age">
</select>
```

*Script*

```
$.getJSON("jsondata.json", function(data) {
    $.each(data.action, function(index, elem) {
        //Append option to name
        $("#name").append($("<option />", {
            value: elem.name,
            text: "Name: " + elem.name
        }));

        //Append age
        $("#age").append($("<option />", {
            value: elem.age,
            text: "Age: " + elem.age
        }));
    });
});
```

Note: Also use only single version of jQuery.

Comment: working fine. thnx... would be grt if you could explain me the jquery code from $each.